# Rails simple form check box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, erb

I have following code :

```
<%= f.input :accepted_terms_and_conditions, as: :boolean, wrapper_html: { class: 'input-checkbox' } %>
</br>
<%= link_to "View terms and condition", "/terms-and-conditions", target: "_blank"  %>
```

however, the checkbox is not appearing for the simple form. Any suggestions in getting the checkbox.

Comment: Where is you open `div` tag?

Comment: thanks for the reply, there is no open div tag

Comment: did you inspect the element?

Answer (score 2):

`f.inputs` is not defined in rails. You may be using `"simple-form"` gem. Simple Form has various views helpers to generates html contents. It has various method such as: `text, radio, email` however `:as => :boolean` options seems to be user defined as its not defined in "simple form" also. You can take look at https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb. f.input work same as f.textbox or similar to rails but it has much more options than bare rails html helpers.
so finally why don't you use like this

> `<%= f.check_box :accepted_terms_and_conditions %>`